# Property 'save' does not exist on type 'IProtein'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to use mongoose "save" function but this error shows ("Property 'save' does not exist on type 'IProtein'.ts(2339)").

I saw that you can solve it by adding "extends mongoose.Document" to the Interface but in the documentation it's not recommended, How can i solve this properly?

Thank you!

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

interface IProtein  {
    seller: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: Number;
    flavour: string;
}

const proteinSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IProtein>({
    seller: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    flavour: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Protein: mongoose.Model<IProtein> = mongoose.model('Protein', proteinSchema);
export { Protein, IProtein };
```

```
export const updateProtein = asyncHandler(async (req: any, res: any) => {
    const currentName: string = req.params.name
    const { name, description, price, flavour } : 
        { name: string | null, description: string | null, price: number | null, flavour: string | null } = req.body

    if (!name && !description && !price && !flavour) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No field got changed' })
    }

    const protein: Protein.IProtein | null = await Protein.Protein.findOne({ currentName }).lean().exec()

    if (!protein) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Protein not found' })
    }

    const duplicate: Protein.IProtein[] | null = await Protein.Protein.find({ currentName }).lean().exec()

    if (duplicate.length > 1) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Duplicate protein title' })
    }

    if (protein)
    {
        if (name)
            protein.name = name
        if (description)
            protein.description = description
        if (price)
            protein.price = price
        if (flavour)
            protein.flavour = flavour

        const updatedProtein = await protein.save() //This is the problem

        res.json(`'${updatedProtein.name}' updated`)
    }
})
```

Comment: Use Mongoose Model type in this line: `const protein: Protein.Protein = await Protein.Protein.findOne({ currentName }).lean().exec()`

Answer (score 2):

I solved my same problem by extending Document from mongoose library.
In this way, objects can have 'save' method.

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Types, Document } from "mongoose";

interface IProtein extends Document {
seller: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
name: string;
description: string;
price: Number;
flavour: string;
```

}